# Подключение к базе данных в Android?

Tags: android, sql

Всем привет. Изучаю программирование на Android. Есть небольшой вопрос.

Для того чтобы записывать данные, использую базу данных SQL lite. Но я хотел узнать, допустим, у меня есть какой-то большой сервис, например, kolesa.kz. Этот сайт использует базу данных MYSQL. Я хочу создать приложение для Android. Как я могу получать данные с сайта? Могу ли я подключаться к базе данных и онлайн передавать их в приложение Android? Или мне нужно, допустим, каждый час делать выгрузку данных и загружать, конвертировать под SQL lite и потом в оффлайне режиме эти данные будут доступны в Андройд?

Comment: http://dajver.blogspot.com/2013/02/json.html вот пример работы с удаленным сервером.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ставишь свой сервер и/или через сокеты с андройда для сервера или через rest запросы